# Plotting every coordinate on a Map in R

Tags: r, gps

I am plotting latitudes and longitudes (300 in total) in R. But my code is only showing a single point on a map. Can anyone please tell me how to visualize all the points on a map ? [image: GPS plots]
My code is mentioned below;

```
 library("ggmap")
 library(maptools)
 library(maps)


 visit.x <- Nlongs
 visit.y <- Nlats

 mp <- NULL
 mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="gray50") 
 # create a layer of borders
 mp <- ggplot() +   mapWorld
 #Now Layer the cities on top
  mp <- mp+ geom_point(aes(x=visit.x, y=visit.y) ,color="blue", size=3) 
  mp



 > Nlongs
   [1] 5.010786 5.010823 5.010862 5.010823 5.010873 5.010872 5.010873 
   5.010823 5.010872

  > Nlats
   [1] 47.29396 47.29397 47.29398 47.29397 47.29396 47.29396 47.29396 
   47.29397 47.29393
```

Comment: Check the output of `ll.visited`, you have only 1 pair of longs and lats. Should `visited` vector contain 300 visited places rather than 1? Furthermore the code should be `visit.y <- ll.visited$lat`, `visit.x <- ll.visited$lon`.  Where is `Nlongs` and `Nlats` coming from?  It's not defined in your example.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yeah, you are right, but its still giving me one point on plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct implentation. You will need to provide/read in a list of names of the 300 visited cities to the `visited` vector.  Here I provide 3.

```
visited <- c("Dijon", "Cambridge", "Los Angeles")
ll.visited <- geocode(visited)
ll.visited


mp <- NULL
mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="gray50") 

# provide ll.visited data to ggplot
mp <- ggplot(ll.visited) + mapWorld

# assign x and y to correspond to lon and lat of ll.visited
mp <- mp + geom_point(aes(x=lon, y=lat), color="blue", size=3) 
mp
```

[image]